# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\RaveController::addToOrdersTables(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Hi I am using RaveFlutterWave as my payment gateway. I want to store an orders whenever a customer finish making payment but I couldn't get pass that error. I don't know what am missing there.
Thanks for your help, here is my code.

```
public function callback(Request  $request)
  {

    // $data = Rave::verifyTransaction(request()->txref);

    $resp = $request->resp;
    $body = json_decode($resp, true);
    $txRef = $body['data']['data']['txRef'];
    $data = Rave::verifyTransaction($txRef);
    
    return redirect()->route('success');
    

  }
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/success', 'RaveController@addToOrdersTables')->name('success');
```

and this is my method for saving the order

```
protected function addToOrdersTables($request, $error)
  { 
    $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
        'billing_email' => $request->email,
        'billing_first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'billing_last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'billing_address' => $request->address,
        'billing_city' => $request->city,
        'billing_town' => $request->town,
        'billing_postalcode' => $request->postalcode,
        'billing_phone' => $request->phone,
        'billing_total' => Cart::getTotal(),
        'error' => $error,
  
      ]);
  
      foreach (Cart::getContent() as $item) 
        {
          
          OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $item->model->id,
            'quantity' => $item->quantity,
          ]);
        }
  }
```

Thanks for concern.

Comment: Please DONT spam TAGS, which are you using 5 or 7?

Comment: Am using laravel-7-x

Comment: You need to typehint request with `Request $request` in your call. I don't know what `$error` is, but you either need to pass it in, take it out of the function call and get it from `$request`, or figure out where it should be coming from.

Comment: I would also suggest renaming the route. `success` and `$error` look contradicting to me. It could be `result/{$status?}` with your method definition as `(Request $request,$status)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass parameter through route as well:

```
Route::get('/success/{error}', 'RaveController@addToOrdersTables')->name('success');
```

And In `addToOrdersTables` method type hint the request using `Request` Like given below:

```
protected function addToOrdersTables(Request $request, $error)
```

Comment: He could also use {error?} to make it an optional parameter - I assume there will not always be an error